How can I figure out the root cause of High Current consumption of the device?
I am working on a device which has two MCUs (MCU A, MCU B). The MCUs are communicating with each other via UART.
The MCU B is an SoC (EFR32) which we are using for Z-Wave communication. So basically, the whole product is a device in which we are trying to add the feature of Z-Wave.
We took an example code and added our code to it, and suddenly the current consumption of the whole device when the device is added to the Z-Wave network has shot up to 11mA. This is too high.
Something is wrong with the code that we have added. And I am saying this because we added the example code to the SoC and added the device to Z-Wave network, and the current consumption was just around 3mA. So, I can very confidently say that the hardware is working fine.
I am very much inexperienced in this area and my overall experience is just two years (as an Embedded SW Developer). Can somebody please tell me which areas of the code do I need to look into to narrow down the problem? The SoC side code uses FreeRTOS for the application. It is a battery operated device. Please tell me if I need to add more information.

Have you checked the electrical specs from the datasheet? I don't have any experience with SiLabs devices but the current consumption of the whole device in different modes in, say, microamps per MHz or consumption of each sub-module (e.g. timers, transmitters, receivers, etc) should be given. Check if your measurement contradicts the datasheet specs.

With respect to energy consumption look at the mJ(/mC) rather than mA - if solution B yields a result at twice the current in one seventh of time compared to A…

Do you have access to a thermal camera?

@winny I do not have access to a thermal camera. How would it help it here?

@greybeard So I learned something new. However, the hardware team always measures in mA and this is for a commercial product.

Do as little as possible in your software. Sleep as much as you can, only wake up when necessary. That should be sound power saving advice more or less for any MCU

High consumption = heats up.

@MrGerber I talked with my senior who worked a lot on this issue. He has experimented with Interrupt based inter-microcommunication and sleep. The problem is, if we put the device to sleep, the HOST (Primary Controller in z-wave) is not able to communicate with the EFR32 properly.

Then you're sleeping more than you can. Hence the wording "as much as you can". It's very hard for people online that does not have access to your hardware design, source code or the inside of the brains of your team, to give very specific advice on how to optimize for current consumption outside the generic style advice you have gotten.

What is the used UART baudrate between the MCUs?

@jens 115200, parity none, 8 data bits

Seems like whatever code you added is stressing one or both MCUs significantly more than the example code or is interacting with external components in a fundamentally different way (pin config).
The more computing has to be done, the more power is consumed.
Same for GPIOs. The more actively pushing/sinking current, the more consumption.
There are several possible approaches.
You could isolate the MCUs electrically and measure them individually, while running the code. That way you might get more information on where you have to look at in the code. If both equally draw too much, it may be something with the communication between the MCUs. If it's just one, you could start looking there.
However, your specific hardware could make this pretty complicated.
A way that requires less hardware interaction is looking at the software right away.
Identify functions that get called more frequently than needed.
Maybe comment out sections of the code that aren't relevant for basic communication or Z-wave to identify them.
Check all Pin-configs. Maybe you accidentally set pins to states where they draw excessive power. (For example open drain inputs with too small/no resistors to limit current).
Make sure you limit read/write actions to non-volatile memory to the bare minimum.
Once you found a power-hungry function/pin, think about how you could improve it. Maybe use interrupts instead of loops. Limit function calls. Set GPIOs to passive if they aren't needed.

Thanks for the answer. I will try to do what you have suggested. However, do you think a poorly written inter-task communication could also contribute to this problem?

A lot of communication is a lot of processing, and seeing as more processing=more consumption, then - yes

@missedSemiColon Definitely. Everything that makes the MCU "work" does add to consumption. Too many R/W commands in a shared memory or other inter-task related functions aren't excluded, there.
